# sklearn KMeans is not working as I only get 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split' on nonEmpty Array

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook

I don't know what is wrong but suddenly `KMeans` from `sklearn` is not working anymore and I don't know what I am doing wrong. Has anyone encountered this problem yet or knows how I can fix it?

```python
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

kmeanModel = KMeans(n_clusters=k, random_state=0)
kmeanModel.fit(allLocations)
```

`allLocations` looks like this:

```python
array([[12.40236   , 51.38086   ],
       [12.40999   , 51.38494   ],
       [12.40599   , 51.37284   ],
       [12.28692   , 51.32039   ],
       [12.41349   , 51.34443   ], ...])
```

and `allLocations.dtype` gives `dtype('float64')`.

The scikit-learn version is 1.0.2 and the NumPy version is 1.22.2 and I am using Jupyter Notebook.

The Error says:

`'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'`

The whole Error looks like this:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-db8e8220c8b9> in <module>
     12 for k in K:
     13     kmeanModel = KMeans(n_clusters=k, random_state=0)
---> 14     kmeanModel.fit(allLocations)
     15     distortions.append(kmeanModel.inertia_)
     16 #Plotting the distortions
    
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cluster\_kmeans.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
   1169         if self._algorithm == "full":
   1170             kmeans_single = _kmeans_single_lloyd
-> 1171             self._check_mkl_vcomp(X, X.shape[0])
   1172         else:
   1173             kmeans_single = _kmeans_single_elkan
    
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cluster\_kmeans.py in _check_mkl_vcomp(self, X, n_samples)
   1026         active_threads = int(np.ceil(n_samples / CHUNK_SIZE))
   1027         if active_threads < self._n_threads:
-> 1028             modules = threadpool_info()
   1029             has_vcomp = "vcomp" in [module["prefix"] for module in modules]
   1030             has_mkl = ("mkl", "intel") in [
    
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\fixes.py in threadpool_info()
    323         return controller.info()
    324     else:
--> 325         return threadpoolctl.threadpool_info()
    326 
    327 
    
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\threadpoolctl.py in threadpool_info()
    122     In addition, each module may contain internal_api specific entries.
    123     """
--> 124     return _ThreadpoolInfo(user_api=_ALL_USER_APIS).todicts()
    125 
    126 
    
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\threadpoolctl.py in __init__(self, user_api, prefixes, modules)
    338 
    339             self.modules = []
--> 340             self._load_modules()
    341             self._warn_if_incompatible_openmp()
    342         else:
    
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\threadpoolctl.py in _load_modules(self)
    371             self._find_modules_with_dyld()
    372         elif sys.platform == "win32":
--> 373             self._find_modules_with_enum_process_module_ex()
    374         else:
    375             self._find_modules_with_dl_iterate_phdr()
    
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\threadpoolctl.py in _find_modules_with_enum_process_module_ex(self)
    483 
    484                 # Store the module if it is supported and selected
--> 485                 self._make_module_from_path(filepath)
    486         finally:
    487             kernel_32.CloseHandle(h_process)
    
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\threadpoolctl.py in _make_module_from_path(self, filepath)
    513             if prefix in self.prefixes or user_api in self.user_api:
    514                 module_class = globals()[module_class]
--> 515                 module = module_class(filepath, prefix, user_api, internal_api)
    516                 self.modules.append(module)
    517 
    
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\threadpoolctl.py in __init__(self, filepath, prefix, user_api, internal_api)
    604         self.internal_api = internal_api
    605         self._dynlib = ctypes.CDLL(filepath, mode=_RTLD_NOLOAD)
--> 606         self.version = self.get_version()
    607         self.num_threads = self.get_num_threads()
    608         self._get_extra_info()
    
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\threadpoolctl.py in get_version(self)
    644                              lambda: None)
    645         get_config.restype = ctypes.c_char_p
--> 646         config = get_config().split()
    647         if config[0] == b"OpenBLAS":
    648             return config[1].decode("utf-8")
    
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Comment: What's `allLocations`?

Comment: I postet it on the bottom of the first code block. It is an 2D numpy Array of type float

Comment: Please post a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Often when problems appear all-of-a-sudden in code that previously works, it's because problems in the new data file(s) - wrong shapes, dtype, etc.  But this error occurs when it's in a `threadpool_info()` call.  It's looking for `config` information - which `BLAS` library to use.  Any recent changes in the machine, its configuration, or updates in the `anaconda` packages?

Comment: I just had the same issue while re-running code that used to work a few months ago. The input data should not have changed, but maybe it has without I noticing?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Downgrading numpy to 1.21.4 made it work again

Comment: This can cause problems with other libraries if you're not working within a venv. I posted a solution that works with all versions of numpy.

Answer (score 57):

**Upgrade `threadpoolctl` to version >3.**

This works for all versions of `numpy`.

Comment: best solution, since *downgrading* numpy can cause issues with other libraries (PyTorch/ Tensorflow etc...).

Comment: Apparently, Upgrading threadpoolctl  alone did not work for me. I had to downgrade the numpy to 1.21.4 as well and then restart the kernel to make it work.

Comment: With sklearn 1.3.1 this is still a problem. sklearn should just require threadpoolctl>3, no?

Comment: For the record - `pip install threadpoolctl==3.1.0` did the trick for me.  Thank you!

Answer (score 17):

I started getting the same error recently. It might have had something to do with a macOS upgrade from Sierra to Catalina, but I found that it was having an issue calculating kMeans when n_clusters = 1. In the following code, I changed my range to be 2:10 instead of 1:10, and it started working.

```
K = range(2,10)

for k in K:

  kmeanModel = KMeans(n_clusters=k)

  kmeanModel.fit(data)

  distortions.append(kmeanModel.inertia_)
```

Comment: This worked for me as well. I wonder if anyone could explain why n_culsters = 1 would cause an issue?

Answer (score 17):

I upgraded `threadpoolctl` from version `2.2.0` to version `3.1.0` and this solved the issue

Comment: This solution has already been posted.

Answer (score 3):

Upgrade threadpoolctl to version 3.0 by doing this:

```
pip install threadpoolctl==3.1.0
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was reviewing this. Could you maybe explain more, why this version needs to be upgraded? btw. your description is not matching the version number in pip. Could you sync that please, so that the description matches the command?

Answer (score 2):

I was getting same error, my senor suggested me to upgrade threadpoolctl.
Use below code

pip install --upgrade threadpoolctl

It is working now.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

None of the options work for MacOS Ventura:
Upgraded threadpoolctl from version 2.2.0 to version 3.1.0
Downgrading numpy to 1.21.4

I solved the issue by moving from Jupiter notebook to Google Colab.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting similar errors, and  problem is solved by 2 step:

1. firstly update the sklearn package using `pip install --upgrade scikit-learn`.
2. secondly update the threadpoolctl using `pip install threadpoolctl==3.1.0` or more update version.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting same errors, this solved the problem for me:                                           pip install -U scikit-learn

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. I was using numpy 1.26.1 and threadpoolctl 2.2.0. I tried upgrading numpy to 1.26.2 keeping the same version of threadpoolctl. That didn't work. Finally I upgraded threadpoolctl as well and the issue got resolved. Now I have numpy 1.26.2 and threadpoolctl 3.2.0