# t-SNE: Sklearn AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nonetype

Any help on the following error? I'm running both PCA and t-SNE and PCA seems to run well, but wherever I run t-SNE, I run into the following error.My code for t-SNE is below:

```
def T_SNE(X,Label,Component=2,title=""):

    tsne = TSNE(n_components=Component)

    tsne_result = tsne.fit_transform(X)
   
    tsne_result_df = pd.DataFrame({'T_SNE_1': tsne_result[:,0], 'T_SNE_2': tsne_result[:,1], 
                                   'label': Label})
    lim = (tsne_result.min()-0.1*tsne_result.min(), tsne_result.max()+0.1*tsne_result.min())
    
    PLOT(TITLE=title,Product="T_SNE",Label=Label,Data=tsne_result_df,lim=lim)

    return tsne_result,tsne
    

result,tsne=T_SNE(X=X_Number,Label=Y_Number,Component=2,title="Digit_data")
```

ERROR BELOW

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Comment: What's the _full_ error message? Your code doesn't call `split`, so it must be coming from somewhere else that you didn't show

Comment: Link to the full error; I couldn't add here the actual code directly coz it is too long: https://acrobat.adobe.com/id/urn:aaid:sc:VA6C2:893cab77-96c3-4f6e-974d-5f2475f942e3

Answer (score 5):

I dont know the solution of this problem but how I see its working, you have to make sure you dont have any negative decimal number in your input data. In that case it will work.

For Example:

```
X = np.array([[0, 0, 0], 
          [0, 1, 1], 
          [1, 0, 1], 
          [1, 1, 1]])
X_embedded = TSNE(n_components=2, learning_rate='auto',init='random', perplexity=3).fit_transform(X)
X_embedded

array([[ 38.441612, -19.513802],
       [ 42.340416,  53.716785],
       [ 81.7535  , -56.929142],
       [-22.048851,  23.391865]], dtype=float32)
```

This is working fine. But if you change one input value like as below:

```
X = np.array([[0, 0, 0], 
          [0, 1, 1], 
          [-1.1, 0, 1], 
          [1, 1, 1]])
X_embedded = TSNE(n_components=2, learning_rate='auto',init='random', perplexity=3).fit_transform(X)
X_embedded

      self.num_threads = self.get_num_threads()
    608         self._get_extra_info()

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\threadpoolctl.py in get_version(self)
    644                              lambda: None)
    645         get_config.restype = ctypes.c_char_p
--> 646         config = get_config().split()
    647         if config[0] == b"OpenBLAS":
    648             return config[1].decode("utf-8")

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

It will through the error. I am not sure about the internal problem it is having but as per my understanding it needs squared distance as per the documentation in the sklearn tsne.

If you make sure you dont have any negative decimal number in your input data it will work.

Disclaimer: This is just my understanding how tsne is working, may be some expert can highlight the other working or the exact issue.

Source: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.manifold.TSNE.html#sklearn.manifold.TSNE.fit

Edit 1:
I am editing this answer as I got one solution. You have make sure the following package with required version and restart the kernal it should work.

```
pip install threadpoolctl==3.1.0
```

Source : [sklearn KMeans is not working as I only get 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split' on nonEmpty Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71352354/sklearn-kmeans-is-not-working-as-i-only-get-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute)

Comment: +1 I was facing an issue with TSNE which was giving attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-split. This resolved the problem

Answer (score 2):

pip install --upgrade threadpoolctl

By upgrading the threadpoolctl to version above 3 should work. Kmeans was also giving the same error, by updating this it should work on the both.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, seems like something to do with the tSNE code not error handling it well. Set your `perplexity` value beforehand, for the data I was working on, perplexity values less than 120 worked fine, but beyond that I got this error. (I also set `init='pca'`, not sure if that makes any difference. Typically perplexity is set anywhere between 5 and 50, as suggested in the original literature.

Comment: Please consider providing some source code to support the given answer explaining show how it solves the problem.