# TSNE in Jupyter

Tags: jupyter, tsne

I have a JN with python 3.9.11, an sklearn 1.4.1.post. When I run t-SNE, I get   'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'.Particularly when raunning "fit_transform" What should I do?

This has worked before in my laptop. Several months later, it doesnt

Comment: Read ['How do I ask a good question?'](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In particular the sections about 'Write a title that summarizes the specific problem' and 'Help others reproduce the problem'. You can provide toy data if necessary to have something for the code to use. Also, if you ran this as a traditional Python script on the command line or entered each line of your code one by one in the Python interpreter/console, I suspect you'd have the same issue if it was running in the same environment. And so 'Jupyter' isn't involved here and while it may be good to mention ...

Comment: <continued> where you are running things, emphasizing Jupyter in the title and the topic tag is not really helping you troubleshoot the source of the issue. Did you read [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73283082/t-sne-sklearn-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-split#comment129421626_73283082) before posting? Beyond that comment having good advice for posting about this topic, that thread seems to ask what you are asking. ('Search, and Research' is emphasized in the guide on how to post that I referenced above.) If that post doesn't help, you should edit ...

Comment: <continued> your post here to include what you tried and why it doesn't. "This has worked before in my laptop. Several months later, it doesnt" So what has changed?

Comment: Are you giving `fit_transform` a `None` argument rather than a numpy array?  or maybe a list that includes a None.  While it's possible there's a version issue here, more likely the problem is with the data/arrays you loaded.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I'm running an example from the scykit-learn:

Comment: import numpy as np
from sklearn.manifold import TSNE

X = np.array([[0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1]])
X_embedded = TSNE(n_components=2, learning_rate='auto',init='random', perplexity=3).fit_transform(X)
X_embedded.shape

Comment: import numpy as np
from sklearn.manifold import TSNE

X = np.array([[0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1]])
X_embedded = TSNE(n_components=2, learning_rate='auto',init='random', perplexity=3).fit_transform(X)
X_embedded.shape

Comment: Thisis the test I did