# KMeans is showing error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split' on nonEmpty Array

Tags: python, k-means

I ran the code below.

```html
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=4)
kmeans.fit(data[0])
```

But got an error : AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'

PS - data[0] is 2D Array

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sklearn KMeans is not working as I only get 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split' on nonEmpty Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71352354/sklearn-kmeans-is-not-working-as-i-only-get-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute)