# t-SNE: Sklearn AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split' on boolean dataframe

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook, tsne

I have a dataframe called star_trek of size 11174 rows × 27577 columns with every column being a boolean.

When I try to visualize the data using TSNE

```
tsne = TSNE(n_components = 2, metric='manhattan', init='pca', verbose=1)

tsne_data = tsne.fit_transform(star_trek.sample(frac = .5))

plt.figure()
plt.scatter(tsne_data[:,0],tsne_data[:,1])
plt.title("tsne in 2-dims on Star Trek data")
plt.show()
```

I get the following error message after this output at verbosity level 1

```
[t-SNE] Computing 91 nearest neighbors...
[t-SNE] Indexed 5587 samples in 0.064s...
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[49], line 3
      1 tsne = TSNE(n_components = 2, metric='manhattan', init='pca', verbose=1)
----> 3 tsne_data = tsne.fit_transform(star_trek.sample(frac = .5))
      5 plt.figure()
      6 plt.scatter(tsne_data[:,0],tsne_data[:,1])

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/manifold/_t_sne.py:1119, in TSNE.fit_transform(self, X, y)
   1117 self._validate_params()
   1118 self._check_params_vs_input(X)
-> 1119 embedding = self._fit(X)
   1120 self.embedding_ = embedding
   1121 return self.embedding_

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/manifold/_t_sne.py:963, in TSNE._fit(self, X, skip_num_points)
    956     print(
    957         "[t-SNE] Indexed {} samples in {:.3f}s...".format(
    958             n_samples, duration
    959         )
    960     )
    962 t0 = time()
--> 963 distances_nn = knn.kneighbors_graph(mode="distance")
    964 duration = time() - t0
    965 if self.verbose:

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/neighbors/_base.py:988, in KNeighborsMixin.kneighbors_graph(self, X, n_neighbors, mode)
    985     A_data = np.ones(n_queries * n_neighbors)
    987 elif mode == "distance":
--> 988     A_data, A_ind = self.kneighbors(X, n_neighbors, return_distance=True)
    989     A_data = np.ravel(A_data)
    991 else:

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/neighbors/_base.py:824, in KNeighborsMixin.kneighbors(self, X, n_neighbors, return_distance)
    817 use_pairwise_distances_reductions = (
    818     self._fit_method == "brute"
    819     and ArgKmin.is_usable_for(
    820         X if X is not None else self._fit_X, self._fit_X, self.effective_metric_
    821     )
    822 )
    823 if use_pairwise_distances_reductions:
--> 824     results = ArgKmin.compute(
    825         X=X,
    826         Y=self._fit_X,
    827         k=n_neighbors,
    828         metric=self.effective_metric_,
    829         metric_kwargs=self.effective_metric_params_,
    830         strategy="auto",
    831         return_distance=return_distance,
    832     )
    834 elif (
    835     self._fit_method == "brute" and self.metric == "precomputed" and issparse(X)
    836 ):
    837     results = _kneighbors_from_graph(
    838         X, n_neighbors=n_neighbors, return_distance=return_distance
    839     )

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/_pairwise_distances_reduction/_dispatcher.py:289, in ArgKmin.compute(cls, X, Y, k, metric, chunk_size, metric_kwargs, strategy, return_distance)
    277     return ArgKmin64.compute(
    278         X=X,
    279         Y=Y,
   (...)
    285         return_distance=return_distance,
    286     )
    288 if X.dtype == Y.dtype == np.float32:
--> 289     return ArgKmin32.compute(
    290         X=X,
    291         Y=Y,
    292         k=k,
    293         metric=metric,
    294         chunk_size=chunk_size,
    295         metric_kwargs=metric_kwargs,
    296         strategy=strategy,
    297         return_distance=return_distance,
    298     )
    300 raise ValueError(
    301     "Only float64 or float32 datasets pairs are supported at this time, "
    302     f"got: X.dtype={X.dtype} and Y.dtype={Y.dtype}."
    303 )

File sklearn/metrics/_pairwise_distances_reduction/_argkmin.pyx:584, in sklearn.metrics._pairwise_distances_reduction._argkmin.ArgKmin32.compute()

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/utils/fixes.py:139, in threadpool_limits(limits, user_api)
    137     return controller.limit(limits=limits, user_api=user_api)
    138 else:
--> 139     return threadpoolctl.threadpool_limits(limits=limits, user_api=user_api)

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/threadpoolctl.py:171, in threadpool_limits.__init__(self, limits, user_api)
    167 def __init__(self, limits=None, user_api=None):
    168     self._limits, self._user_api, self._prefixes = \
    169         self._check_params(limits, user_api)
--> 171     self._original_info = self._set_threadpool_limits()

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/threadpoolctl.py:268, in threadpool_limits._set_threadpool_limits(self)
    265 if self._limits is None:
    266     return None
--> 268 modules = _ThreadpoolInfo(prefixes=self._prefixes,
    269                           user_api=self._user_api)
    270 for module in modules:
    271     # self._limits is a dict {key: num_threads} where key is either
    272     # a prefix or a user_api. If a module matches both, the limit
    273     # corresponding to the prefix is chosed.
    274     if module.prefix in self._limits:

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/threadpoolctl.py:340, in _ThreadpoolInfo.__init__(self, user_api, prefixes, modules)
    337     self.user_api = [] if user_api is None else user_api
    339     self.modules = []
--> 340     self._load_modules()
    341     self._warn_if_incompatible_openmp()
    342 else:

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/threadpoolctl.py:371, in _ThreadpoolInfo._load_modules(self)
    369 """Loop through loaded libraries and store supported ones"""
    370 if sys.platform == "darwin":
--> 371     self._find_modules_with_dyld()
    372 elif sys.platform == "win32":
    373     self._find_modules_with_enum_process_module_ex()

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/threadpoolctl.py:428, in _ThreadpoolInfo._find_modules_with_dyld(self)
    425 filepath = filepath.decode("utf-8")
    427 # Store the module if it is supported and selected
--> 428 self._make_module_from_path(filepath)

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/threadpoolctl.py:515, in _ThreadpoolInfo._make_module_from_path(self, filepath)
    513 if prefix in self.prefixes or user_api in self.user_api:
    514     module_class = globals()[module_class]
--> 515     module = module_class(filepath, prefix, user_api, internal_api)
    516     self.modules.append(module)

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/threadpoolctl.py:606, in _Module.__init__(self, filepath, prefix, user_api, internal_api)
    604 self.internal_api = internal_api
    605 self._dynlib = ctypes.CDLL(filepath, mode=_RTLD_NOLOAD)
--> 606 self.version = self.get_version()
    607 self.num_threads = self.get_num_threads()
    608 self._get_extra_info()

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/threadpoolctl.py:646, in _OpenBLASModule.get_version(self)
    643 get_config = getattr(self._dynlib, "openblas_get_config",
    644                      lambda: None)
    645 get_config.restype = ctypes.c_char_p
--> 646 config = get_config().split()
    647 if config[0] == b"OpenBLAS":
    648     return config[1].decode("utf-8")

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

I have tried changing the perplexity and init values as per [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73283082/t-sne-sklearn-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-split) and I have also tried downgrading numpy to 1.21.4 and upgrading threadpoolctl as per [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71352354/sklearn-kmeans-is-not-working-as-i-only-get-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute) but the problem persists.

Comment: surely there are some more random things you can try :)  What you really need to do is figure out is what is producing this `None`.